# Incorporating base memory addresses in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, base-address

The base address I found for a memory location in an application was in the syntax `"application_name.exe" + 0007856` (<- or any other number, this is just an example). My question is, how would I find the address for `"application_name.exe"` in C++? I'm not sure but this was the method I used:

```
HANDLE proc_handle = OpenProcess(//parameters go here to open the process);
void * base_add = (void*)proc_handle;    //to store the address of the process
```

If that method is correct, the first question I asked on how to get the application's address is answered which leads me to my second question: since the base address for the specific memory location was `"application_name.exe" + 0007856`, can I just do this?:

```
DWORD specific_memory_base_add = (DWORD)base_add + 0x0007856
```

Can I use the address I found from `"application_name.exe"` and add it to `0x0007856` using `+`? I've tried it and it didn't seem to work. If that is not correct, what is the correct method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieving the base address of a module in another process requires to enumerate the process' modules and retrieve the module names to find a match.

To enumerate the modules loaded into a process call [`EnumProcessModules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631.aspx). Once you have the list of modules call [`GetModuleBaseName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683196.aspx) for each module to find the one you are looking for (application_name.exe). The `HMODULE` for this module is a pointer (in the target process' address space) to the beginning of the module, it's base address. You can use this to add your offset.

Comment: I get "undefined reference to EnumProcessModules@16". I included psapi.h

Comment: Including psapi.h isn't enough. You must also **link** to Psapi.lib.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about Windows (should you have tagged `winapi`?) you can get the base address of a loaded module with [`GetModuleHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). A module doesn't have a base address until it is loaded (although the linker can specify a preferred base address, the loader doesn't have to use/respect this).

Comment: Is the method I used above incorrect? And after I do get the address of the application, how do I add it to 0x0007856 to get the actual base address?